# Execute ThreadPoolExecutor asynchronously but use only 1 process and 1 thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Can I limit `ThreadPoolExecutor` to use only 1 processor core, 1 process and 1 thread at the same time but run a function asynchronously?

```
import time, concurrent.futures

def ts(start):
    return round(time.perf_counter() - start, 3)

def fn(sec):
    print(f'{ts(start)}\tstart sleeping {sec}')
    time.sleep(sec)

def main():
    lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        executor.map(fn, lst)

start = time.perf_counter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print(f'{ts(start)}\tfinish')

# 0.001   start sleeping 1
# 1.008   start sleeping 1
# 2.01    start sleeping 1
# 3.021   start sleeping 1
# 4.024   start sleeping 1
# 5.038   start sleeping 1
# 6.051   finish
```

I'd like to run all the functions successively but instead of waiting the result after each run, wait all the results at the end like this:

```
# 0.001   start sleeping 1
# 0.002   start sleeping 1
# 0.003   start sleeping 1
# 0.004   start sleeping 1
# 0.005   start sleeping 1
# 0.006   start sleeping 1
# 1.051   finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread pool works as follows, it starts a task in a thread and until it returns control the thread is busy, even if it sleeps. Therefore, if you want to run them in parallel, you have to either use multiple threads or use asyncio coroutines.

Here is `asyncio` sample:

```
import asyncio
import time

def foo():
    print('Start ...')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('... End')

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    count = range(2)
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, foo) for i in count]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output

```
Start ...
Start ...
... End
... End
```

Comment: How can I do this with asyncio coroutines? Can you show code example?

Comment: Modified answer

Comment: I know that `asyncio.sleep(5)` will work. My question is how to run blocking code like `time.sleep(sec)`. `time.sleep(sec)` MUST be inside the function.

Comment: Ok, you can run blocking code using run_in_executor.

Comment: I have an error trying to run your code on Windows Python 3.8.5: `\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:1860: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Remove async before foo function

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that only one process/thread works at the same time in `run_in_executor`?

Comment: Process is one. But pool of threads is used under the hood. It is impossible to fulfill your requirements with one thread.